# Asp.net Core logout from other site with $ajax

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a site http://my-site.com and a user is authenticated with a cookie

The logout url is http://my-site.com/logout

the code for logout is

```
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

if I go manually on http://my-site.com/logout, cookie is removed and user is logout => OK

if I'm on another site ex : http://localhost:5000 and execute the script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var settings = 
    {
        url : 'http://my-site.com/logout', 
        "crossDomain": true,
        "method": "GET",
        "cache": false,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
    }
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
});
</script>
```

I have no error, but the authentication cookie is not removed.

All Cors options have been set like

```
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CONFIG",
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:5000")
                );
    });
```

Do you have an idea ?
Is there another way to log out a user from an ajax script from another domain?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Cookie Authentication would append a cookie with HttpContext.SignInAsync,and the name of the cookie could be setted by yourself,For Example:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddCookie(option =>
                    {
                      option.Cookie.Name = "MyCookie";
                      option.LoginPath = "/Home/Login";
                    });
```

And Cookie has the domain property,`HttpContext.SignOutAsync` will only affect the cookie in your  current app's domain

If you just want to logout,You could try

```
 HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete("MyCookie", new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieOptions() { Domain = "localhost" });
```

to achieve your purpose

[image]

And you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-7.0) about share auth cookie amoung apps